# Sysinternal's Process Explorer v14 doesn't show network activity

Tags: windows-xp, process-explorer

The new version of Process Explorer shows network activity history, but it doesn't in one of my computers.  This particular PC runs Windows XP SP3 and it has just been reformatted so everything is "fresh".  I have even installed WinPCap and Microsoft Network monitor, in case some of these drivers were necessary, but the graph stays in 0.

Any ideas why this could happen?

I would ask in Sysinternal's forum, but I really don't want to register in yet another forum.

Comment: You need to run the program as an admin to see the network I/O.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. I've just tried running the process as admin, but it doesn't work either.  Besides, I think my user account has admin rights.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: Yes, I do. I've just downloaded version 15.13 and I don't see any network I/O information. However, other tools, like Nirsoft AdapterWatch show all the info.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't get any reading on the Network graph in my XP VM either. I would assume it's either a bug or simply not supported on XP.

Comment: No solution here either: http://forum.sysinternals.com/network-grapf_topic26559.html

Comment: Or just use wireshark, it's probably more feature laden anyway.

Comment: Version 15.23 seems to be working now...

Comment: Why don't you use tcpview from the sysinternal package?
That should do the job for you. :)

Comment: Just FYI, the network history is *also* not available in [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) on XP. So the information might simply not be available.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same issue as you.

There is an option under File, called "Show Details for All Processes". When I enabled that,
I could see the Network graph.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: It's due to UAC. If you have UAC disabled (properly), the issue does not happen.

Comment: 'UAC disabled' and 'properly' should not be in the same sentence.

Comment: Also XP doesn't have UAC (in reference to original post)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble (various versions of PE), but now the problem has gone away!  An indirect fix, but quite painless.

For whatever obscure reason, my Event Viewer was not working in a new installation of Windows 7, and I found this link:
 http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-event-log-error-4201-instance-name-not-recognized/  (summary inserted below) after Scannow had failed to fix it, this worked immediately.

But I have just now noticed that in Process Explorer 16.04 that it is all working!
Disk delta, disk write, disk read, network send, network receive - all there.

The event viewer problem seems (judging from numerous reports of problems) to be a deep flaw in W7, and apparently with other ramifications, inc. fax service.  This would now seem to be connected with that failure of permissions.

I hope this helps in a wider sense than just PE.

============

1. Start Windows in Safe mode  [actually it worked without doing this, on the fly]
2. Open the "C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI" folder
3. Right-click on the RtBackup folder and choose Properties
4. Click the Security tab, and click the Edit button.
5. Click Add
6. Type SYSTEM and hit ENTER
7. Enable "Full control" Permission to "Allow"
8. Click OK, and then click Yes when asked for confirmation.
9. Restart Windows (in Normal mode), and verify if the Windows Event Service has started. [reboot was required]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please include the relevant information from the link in your answer? We avoid link-only answers because they become unhelpful if the link ever breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the latest version of Process Explorer.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Try filing a bug at http://forum.sysinternals.com/process-explorer-bugs_topic6397_page66.html.

Comment: Don't waste your time, just get an old version from the link I meticulously tracked down for you :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can download Process Explorer v.8.20 here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20040202101508/http://www.sysinternals.com/ntw2k/freeware/procexp.shtml

OR likely most any other version from here:
http://goo.gl/jfEQ7

PS Thank You Mark Russinovich

PPS Most likely a bug or artifact of engineered obsolescence. Windows XP is now "unsupported" so Microsoft has no incentive whatsoever to care.

Comment: We normally would like more then just a single link.  Furthermore its not "clearly a bug 3 and half years later.

Comment: Confirmed that it's still an issue with Process Explorer 15.22.0.0 on Windows XP SP2.

PS Thanks, you just caused my XP box to bluescreen trying to appease you. Fully unpacking the issue could take hours if not days or weeks. Is it worth it? No. The OP and people finding this on Google come here with only one goal in sight: Get Process Explorer to show them TCP-IP connections. Which my solution grants them.

Comment: Additionally - Process Explorer 8 is more than 10 times smaller.